# Appending a css class to a textbox javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to add the css class named **color** to the textbox define inside the javascript below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Colors and price: #'+ counter + ' : </label>' + '<input name="colors[]" value=""  >');

</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Colors and price: #'+ counter + ' : </label>' + '<input name="colors[]" value="" class="color" >');
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean, to the input?

simply

```
'<input name="colors[]" value="" class="color">'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
newTextBoxDiv.siblings("input:text[name='colors[]']").addClass('color');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the `newTextBoxDiv` then use:

```
newTextBoxDiv.addClass('color');
```

If it is the input then:

```
'<input name="colors[]" value="" class="color">'
```